# Font Similar to Casablanca Book Condensed

Tags: fonts, font-identification, free

I'm trying to find a font similar to [Casablanca Book Condensed](http://www.fonts.com/font/international-typefounders-inc/casablanca/book-condensed) which you can test drive.

[image: Casablankca Book Condensed]

What I'm trying to find to match the 'S':

[image]

Ultimately I'm looking for something free but the cheaper the better. I've tried to look through Google Fonts but didn't find anything that matched what I was looking for. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Are you looking for a font that will be used for text/headlines, or just the 's' for a logo or piece of art?

Comment: Logo and image files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Fiesta Font](http://www.dafont.com/fiesta.font):

[image]

Not identical, but free and close.

Comment: "Free for personal use"

Answer (score 3):

Romeo Condense Medium, on myfont.com
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/romeo/mediumcondensed/

[image]

Comment: That's about the same price as Casablanca Book Condensed but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: this seems to be another option, site seems a little sketch though
http://www.ufonts.com/fonts/romeomediumcond.html

Comment: Yeah they want me to install an application to 'download' the font. I think i'll take a pass xD

Comment: there is an option to select the TTF

Comment: @Howdy_McGee If I could downvote the ufont link, I would. There's no way that download is approved by the Font Bureau (the people who made the font). Someone here is welcome to correct me but that's almost certainly a pirated file.

Answer (score 3):

You could see if one of these suits you:

[Deco Tech](http://www.dafont.com/decotech.font)

[Mouse Deco](http://www.dafont.com/mouse-deco.font?text=SUPER+GREAT)

In general, you're looking for a **geometric** font. The keyword **deco** will help you too.

As always, with free fonts, make sure you have the proper license to use the font in your setting.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a silly suggestion, and forgive me if it is. But why not - if you plan on using the font solely for images - create the shapes yourself? That way, you can't go cheaper.

Note: I am not suggesting to obtain/clone it, simply mimic it in actual Bézier curves.